# Multiple Bar charts on the same X-axis and Y-axis in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot multiple bar charts on the same x-axis and y-axis. I do not want stacked or grouped bar charts. I just want to have multiple bar charts side by side with a long x-axis where x-axis ticks repeat based on the number of bar charts and y-axis which is shared along bar charts and is placed on the leftmost side of the graph.

Here is my code but it does not produce the output what I want

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools



trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
)
trace3 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
)


fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, specs=[[{}], [{}], [{}]],
                          shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.001)


fig.append_trace(trace1, 3, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='')

pyo.plot(fig, filename='bar-charts-with-shared-axis.html')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you want that:
[image: Your output]

Code:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
)
trace3 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3,
                          shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.001)

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 3)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='')

pyo.plot(fig, filename='bar-charts-with-shared-axis.html')
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot. One more question. I need to put a dropdown menu on that chart. I know how to do this but I particularly want to have multiple selection dropdown menus where I'll be able to select 2 country while unselect other 2 country simultaneously. Is it possible? If it is I'll share my code

Comment: @NodarOkroshiashvili, you can ask another question) It is possible in `Dash`: follow this [link](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/dropdown) and look at the second example. But you need graph in `plotly`, and I cannot find any parameters in [ref](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-updatemenus) or after googling. So I didn't know how to do that in `plotly`

Comment: I was also googling and did not find anything. As you say I do not want to use ```Dash``` as I cannot use it without the local server. I need a standalone HTML file. I solved this problem by using Plotly's legends which act as multiple dropdown menus. So, thanks a lot, saved my day.